# Submit ajax form and stay on same page not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to store comments from users in my databse. When a user submits I don't want to redirect them to a new page.
I have the following code but it's not working.

My HTML code:

```
<form id="formA" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="commentData" name="commentData" type="text" >'
<input type="submit" value="toDb" id="toDB" name="toDB" /></form>
```

Javascript:

```
var frm = $('#formA');

$(document).submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

    url: frm.attr('action'),

    type: frm.attr('method'),

    data: frm.serialize(),

    success: function(html) {

        alert('ok');

    }

});
});
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
//Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM comments order by RAND() LIMIT 5";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

if (!$rs) {
     echo 'Could not run query ' . mysql_error();
     exit;
}

$dt1=date("Y-m-d");

if(isset($_POST['toDB'])){
  $dataA = $_POST['commentData'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(id, comment, datum)VALUES(DEFAULT,'$dataA', '$dt1')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
mysql_close();
```

When I click on the submit button it will stay on the same page and show the alert but the data of the input field is not inserted in my database. When I remove the e.preventDefault() the data goes into the database but the page redirects to test.php

Tried different things but can't figure it out.
Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: put `var frm = $('#formA');` in side `$(document).submit(function(e) {` and check once please.

Comment: `$dataA` should be sanitized to prevent injections. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php Also note about mysql_, should be using mysqli or pdo, then you could use prepared statements. If you give `datum` a default timestamp you won't have to insert the date everytime. Also the `DEFAULT` I haven't seen before but if you have the field auto incrementing you don't need to send it.

Comment: Thansk for the quick response but it is still not working unfortunately. These changes make no difference.

Comment: Have you loaded `jquery.min.js` ?

Comment: Yes I have loaded jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: Check what post data your xhr request contains.  I did a quick test with `.serialize()` and it didn't contain the submit button key or value for me, which your PHP depends on.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console ?

Comment: No errors in my console. @tobymackenzie I don't fully understand what you mean but I have tried to echo $dataA and it gives the correct data en when I echo $_POST['toDB'] it gives 'toDB'. Sorry I don't get what you mean, am not very good in PHP but understand the bigger picture most of the time.

Comment: What I mean is irrelevant if you are getting the proper POST data when sending your AJAX request.  If `$dataA` is being output, then that means your `INSERT` code is being run.  Try echoing `mysql_error()` and seeing if it says anything.  If nothing, echo your SQL statement.

Comment: BTW, what I meant about `serialize()` is: `jQuery('<form><input id="commentData" name="commentData" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="toDb" id="toDB" name="toDB" /></form>').find('#commentData').val('foo').last().serialize()` === `'commentData=foo'` when run in a JS console for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form submits and does not stay on the same page because of the action attribute on the form, and the normal submit button.

Which leads to your `.submit()` method including `.preventDefault()` probably not being interpreted after the html is loaded either.

You could do something along the lines of this:

```html
<html>
  ...
  <body>
  ...
    <form id="formA" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="commentData" name="commentData" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="toDb" id="toDB" name="toDB" />
    </form>
  ...
  </body>
  <script>
   ...script here...
  </script>
 </html>
```

And the javascript could be something along the lines of:

```js
( function( $ )
  {
    var submit = $( 'input[id=toDB]' );
    $( submit ).on
    (
      'click',
      function( event )
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $( this ).parent();

        // Get form fields
        var data = $( form ).serializeArray(), obj = {}, j = 0;
        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
        {
          if( data[i].name in obj )                                                                  
          {
            var key = data[i].name + '_' + j;
            obj[key] = data[i].value;
            j++;
          }
          else
          {
            obj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
          }
        };

        // Make AJAX request
        $.ajax
        (
          {   
            url: $( form ).attr( 'action' ),    
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'toDB=' + JSON.stringify( obj ),    
            success: function( data, textStatus, xhr )
            {
              // Do something with data?
              ...    
              alert( 'ok' );    
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }( jQuery )
);
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rikkotec/s5vffrL9) for yourself.

You can tell it is working because you get a console error that the request destination is not found - 404 - though the page does not refresh, you stay right where you are...with a proper page to submit to it works fully.

EDIT

I modified the setting of 'data' in the `ajax()` call so that the form fields are set as a json string to a POST variable [toDB].

So in your PHP you would do:

```
$datas = json_decode( $_POST['toDB'], true );
```

And now your `$datas` variable is an associative array containing all your form fields names and values. I'm not 100% on this next statement, but you may need to use PHP's `stripslashes()` method on the POSTED data prior to using `json_decode()`

i.e.:

```
//Connect to database server
mysql_connect( "localhost", "user", "" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db( "test" ) or die( mysql_error() );
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM comments order by RAND() LIMIT 5";
$rs = mysql_query( $strSQL );

if( !$rs ) 
{
  echo 'Could not run query ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
}

$dt1=date("Y-m-d");

if( isset( $_POST['toDB'] ) )
{
  $datas = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['toDB'] ), true );
  $dataA = $datas['commentData'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO comments( id, comment, datum )VALUES( DEFAULT, '" . $dataA . "', '" . $dt1 . "' );";
  $result=mysql_query( $sql );
}
mysql_close();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: With this code I'm getting an error in my console: The property or method Stringnify is not supported by this object

Comment: Its supposed to be `JSON.stringify()`, I had a typo.  Its fixed, with a jsfiddle link now as well.

Comment: Thanks, it does stay on the same page but nothing is inserted into my database. I don't get it. I have been trying to fix this for days!

Comment: Yeah, with this solution - I made an edit so you can access the posted data from your PHP... see the edit above, that should do the trick for you.

Comment: Yeaaaaaaah! It works! Thank you so much! Could never figure this out on my own.

Comment: Glad we were able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it via form submit event

```
var frm = $('#formA');
frm.submit(function(e) {
  //....
  //....
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And yes, sanitize DB inserts with `mysql_real_escape_string($dataA)` to prevent SQL injections.

**EDIT**
sorry, incomplete answer (still you need to use submit on form, not on document)

**EDIT2** :) wrong usage of $(this) :)

```
$('#formA').submit(function(e) {  
  var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({   
    url: formAction,    
    type: 'POST',     // try uppercase, 'post' !== 'POST', dont know if this must be uppercase or can be lowercase
    data: formData, // or try  $(this).serializeArray()    
    success: function(html) {    
        alert('ok');    
    })
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT2.5**: there can be problems with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
you need to make some modifications:
`var formData = new FormData(this);`
and add some options to AJAX call

```
mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
contentType: false,
cache: false,
processData:false
```

found this page with example
http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

try that UPPERCASE / lowercase `POST`, and then try to remove `multipart/form-data` if you dont need it (file upload etc...)

**EDIT3**
with multipart form, maybe you should use this in PHP in some cases to access your post data `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']`

Comment: Thanks for helping out but It makes no difference. Still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: use console to watch some errors, maybe there will be answer

Comment: try my edit2 block and check that url, hope there will be answer for you

Comment: the best solution to solve this issue is do a print_r($_POST);exit; at the top of the test.php file. and then in your success function of jquery type console.log(html) and see what output you got is the data posted as it should be ?

Comment: I'm lost in all the edits. Where do you use the $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] in my PHP. And in the second edit you are suggesting some modification, does that mean replace var formData = $(this).serialize(); with var formData = new FormData(this);

Comment: sorry, renamed one "edit2" to "edit 2.5"  :)   that $GLOBALS, just try to use it somewhere at start of php script, to check if it is filled or not and compare it to $_POST, in some cases, POST is empty, GLOBALS[...] are filled.  <?php var_export($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']); ?>, and check your debug window (F12 in chrome and firefox) - tab "network" to watch network communication and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Add return false at the end of the script to prevent redirecting